# border-bottom bug in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

In Microsoft Edge browser after hovering an element border-bottom set the color of the bottom element. Bug? Look at jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Experimenter/65eLh89r/

```css
a{
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
a:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">0</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the bug. Could you be more clear about the bug that you are experiencing. That would help.

Comment: You should reproduced it in Windows 10, Microsoft Edge. It's work only there! So just hover the list items of ul and you will see that border disappear sometimes. There is a bug for sure, it was tested on a few machines. I will attach the screenshot. http://screenpresso.com/=s5Qkb

Comment: I created an issue internally for the Edge team, and will update when I hear back from the team that owns this bit of the code.

Comment: More than 2 years later and still waiting for a fix...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same issue and created kind of a hack or workaround this bug.  What worked for me was to use `margin-bottom: -1px;` and `border-bottom: 2px solid gray;`

so mentioned example would look like:

```
a{
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
a:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, setting the height as @rjgamer suggested works, but when it's not desirable, playing with margin-bottom worked.

Comment: This works, but if the elements are in a scrollable container (overflow-y: auto), the scrollbar will always be shown in IE, Firefox and Edge because of the negative margin.

Comment: To fix the issue I mentioned, you can simply remove the negative margin from the last element.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem. It appears if the height or width is dynamic and has not a rounded pixel size. As solution example: Change the height to 40px (or what else) and the hover effect works.

But Microsoft should really fix this "designbug" asap... May Edge is fast, but the rendering is not perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is use `a{top: 0; position: relative;}`. It's working for me.